# Can't load app with React v18. Maybe <StrictMode> to blame?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get my app to render for the first time and running into issues with React v18 and `<StrictMode>`

When I run this code:

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
      <App />
  </StrictMode>,
);
```

I get this error:

```
[eslint]
src/index.js
Line 51:4: 'StrictMode is not defined react/jsx-no-undef
```

I know React v18 changed some stuff, and [this article](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-reacdom-render-no-longer-supported-in-react-18) talks about `<StrictMode>` a little ... but what do I need to do? I've never had to import it before.

Answer (score 1):

`StrictMode` is an exotic component from React itself - you need to import it from React in order to use it.

```
import React, { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
      <App />
  </StrictMode>,
);
```

Comment: That got rid of that issue, but now I get this in the console: Uncaught Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>. So I tried <StrictMode><Routes><App> and the closing tags, and I get this: Uncaught Error: [App] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>. Adding <React.Fragment> doesn't help.

Comment: That looks like a completely different issue relating to React Router and the contents of App (which isn't in the question)